# SQL AND OR operators

Tags: sql, boolean-expression

Why this below query ONLY brings `deptno = 10`?
Why is not not bringing rows of `job IN ('MANAGER','SALESMAN') and deptno = 30` results?

```
select * 
from emp 
where deptno=10 
  and ((job IN ('MANAGER','SALESMAN') and deptno = 30) or (1=1));
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `predicate logic` (in general and specifically in SQL)? Have a look at it to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

`(1=1)` is always `TRUE`.
So any condition/boolean expression combined with `OR` with that condition, like:

```
(job IN ('MANAGER','SALESMAN') and deptno = 30) or (1=1)
```

will also be always `TRUE`.
This makes your `WHERE` clause equivalent to:

```
where deptno=10 and TRUE
```

and simpler:

```
where deptno=10
```

If you want the rows of the table of `deptno=10` and the rows of `deptno=30` only if `job IN ('MANAGER','SALESMAN')` then you should have:

```
where deptno=10 or ((job IN ('MANAGER','SALESMAN') and deptno = 30)
```

Comment: Yes, so in other words, these are logical operators, not spoken language words that can be interpreted differently.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó if you mean that in everyday language we don't always use the logical operators as they are defined in SQL then you are right.

Comment: Yes, but not just in SQL: it is math, so it is everywhere where there is predicate logic.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó of course the operators are defined in math and they are implemented in SQL or in programming languages.

Comment: Sometimes it can be useful to visualize the result or combination of various boolean statements by writing an equivalence in the form of a case expression, such as

*where
1=case when <some condition I want to be true> then 1 else 0 end*; 

I don't recommend writing production code in  such a way, although by the time it gets parsed and optimized it will generally be functionally no different.

Answer (score -1):

You probably wanted to do this:

```
select * 
from emp 
where (deptno=10 )
  or ((job IN ('MANAGER','SALESMAN') and deptno = 30));
```